# Flash as3 dragging Movieclips from Scrollpane component into a movieclip/stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scrollpane

Hi im new on this board hope you can help me.

Im trying to make a flash map game.Now i have got items in a Movieclip and want this Movieclip into a scrollpane component but i have got probs cause the dragging dont go outside of the scrollpane.

Here is my Code

```
container.mc_item.buttonMode = true;

container.mc_item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
function onDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
container.mc_item.startDrag();
}
container.mc_item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
function onUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
container.mc_item.stopDrag();
trace(container.mc_item.dropTarget.parent.name);   // this is the command that tells us which area the mc_item was dropped on
}
container.scrollpane.source= container.mc_item;
```

Please help

---

I uploaded the source in cs4.
Would be great if you can make the each dynamic _mc in scrollpane dragable, to drag into the movieclip outside.
Is it possible to give each of the _mc in the scrollpane a label?

http://www.speedshare.org/download.php?id=5324318F11

Thanks

Comment: Could you try explaining in more detail what it is you want, and what the current behavior is? Maybe post your SWF as it is now.

Comment: Ok See this is my problem I have got dynamic Movieclips in a scrollbar component now i want them each dragable outside of the scrollpane into a Movieclip. 
Now this is my DEMO 


http://www.speedshare.org/download.php?id=37410CEB11

Here is the SOURCE 
http://www.speedshare.org/download.php?id=5B6A311C11
 Would be realy happy if you can help me out of this damt... 
Via Drag And Drop

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you either need to write your own scroll-pane component, or (easier I think), add some code so that when you start dragging the item in the list, you create a duplicate of the item  instead (which is not added as a child to the scrollpane), and drag that instead. Don't forget to remove it when you drop it :)

Comment: I don't have access to CS5.5, so I can't open your file. You haven't made any mistakes (probably), it just doesn't work like you want it to work :)